# Publish/Subscribe with different delegate types

Tags: c#

I'm using a simple sort of message broker in my app, where plugins can register to be notified for custom events. Uhm.. like this :

```
class MessageBroker
{
    Dictionary<string,List<Delegate>> SubscribersToEvent;

    void SubscribeToEvent(string eventName, Delegate callback);
    object RaiseEvent(string eventName);
}
```

This works fine and dandy as long as I use the same Delegate (and the same parameter list for all events)

Is there any clean way I can subscribe/trigger events that use custom delegates in that the number and type of parameters might change for each type of event?

ie.  In the end I want to do something like:

```
  messageBroker.RaiseEvent("button1_click", new object[] { button1, parameter2, param2} )
```

and that in turn to be calling subscribed method(s)

```
   void CallbackToButton1_click(Buttton btn, string p1, int p2)
```

Comment: This would be doable with reflection, at the cost of speed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar problem by simply passing in a dictionary to the delegate as additional parameter which holds all properties specific to that event only. The disadvantage is that the compiler can't enforce that all parameters are passed but it has served me quite well and actually never caused any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel...  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122(v=pandp.20).aspx